# Is there a trick to logging into the ecobee developers portal?

Tags: ecobee-api

I tried to register on the ecobee developers sign-in page, and nothing happens. The page just refreshes into the "Log in to become an ecobee developer" page again and doesn't move forward.
I've tried different browsers, and incognito mode, clearing my cache and a different machine, same issue.
I emailed the ecobee support team and they just sent me here, so any advice would be greatly appreciated!
Nicholas.

Answer (score 2):

Go into your app and disable 2 factor authentication.  I did this and I am good to go!!